# <!DOCTYPE> Declaration using PowerShell 5.0

Tags: html, powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell script whereby the HTML output needs to conform to HTML 5 standards. By default the declaration is written as `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

Is it possible to change the default declaration to conform to HTML 5 standards? e.g. `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Cheers.

Comment: You can do a string replacement using `$htmlData.Replace(oldValue, newValue)`. Assuming your HTML source text is stored inside `$htmlData`.

Comment: This works great, although I had to modify it slightly as the string is derived from a file after the content has been exported to HTML.

I went with:-

`(Get-Content $filepath).Replace('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">', '<!DOCTYPE html>') | Set-Content $filepath`

Comment: Good to know that it worked for you. Please don't forget to mark answer/up vote if that helps.

Comment: @SavindraSingh You do realize that you need to post an actual answer before someone can accept or upvote it, don't you?

Comment: Ohh I am sorry.. I didn't realize that while posting that comment. My bad! :(

Comment: No problem, please post as answer and I'll happily accept :)